# Set crossOriginIsolated Svelte and SvelteKit

Tags: cors, svelte, sveltekit

I'm new in Svelte and SvelteKit and I'm getting this error when trying to execute a worker:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': SharedArrayBuffer transfer requires self.crossOriginIsolated.
```

I know I need to set the headers (I'm moving from React to Svelte), but how/where do I set the headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution was setting Vite's *"configureServer"* in the *"svelte.config.js"* (here's a link to [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configureserver)). The implementation looks like this:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';

/** @type {import('vite').Plugin} */
const viteServerConfig = {
    name: 'log-request-middleware',
    configureServer(server) {
        server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
            next();
        });
    }
};

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        vite: {
            plugins: [viteServerConfig]
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 3):

As of June 2023, the Svelte-Kit config syntax seems to have changed and Gum Rick's solution doesn't work verbatim.

As an alternate, the Vite plugin can be defined and configured in `vite.config.js`:

```js
// vite.config.js

import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

/** @type {import('vite').Plugin} */
const viteServerConfig = () => ({
    name: 'add-headers',
    configureServer: (server) => {
        server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
            next();
        });
    }
});

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit(), viteServerConfig()]
});
```

Comment: I'm using google one click auth and while this solution seems to not have any error, it causes my google popup to be a white screen

Comment: @ChenW The policies in the headers might have to be tweaked as per your requirement. This answer is merely about how to set the headers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.